Why does the disassembly of this function show a two-operand idiv?
I wrote the following C program:
#include "stdio.h"

__declspec(noinline) void DivideTest(int num, int denom)
{
    int quo = num / denom;
    int rem = num % denom;
    printf("Quotient: %d\nRemainder: %d\n", quo, rem);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Use volatile variables to prevent result from being hardcoded.
    volatile int num = 20;
    volatile int denom = 3;
    DivideTest(num, denom);

    return 0;
}

As expected, the output is as follows:
Quotient: 6
Remainder: 2

However, when I compile in release mode (i.e. with optimizations enabled), debug the program in Visual Studio, and look at the disassembly, it shows DivideTest using a two-operand idiv:
_DivideTest:
push esi
mov esi,edx
mov eax,ecx
cdq
idiv eax,esi

Disassembling using dumpbin produces the same result. But every source I've found (
example) says that idiv can only take one operand.
When I try to assemble code using a two-operand idiv, it fails, as I would expect based on the documentation. Why does the disassembly show a two-operand idiv?

Your disassembler (the Visual Studio debugger?) is inventing its own asm syntax to describe idiv.
In the machine code, the EDX:EAX operand (dividend input and rem:quo output) is implicit, implied by the opcode, which is why there's no way to choose different registers.
Mainstream asm syntax (including AT&T, and also Intel's and AMD's manuals) mirror that choice, making it a one-operand instruction with only the explicit divisor.
But there's no reason a flavour of assembly couldn't instead require EAX as a first operand, e.g. as a way to set the operand-size when there's a memory source operand.  (Like idiv eax, [ecx] instead of idiv dword ptr [ecx]).  MASM already does that for rep movsd vs. rep movs es:[edi], ds:[esi], which Intel actually documents, note the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs of the Description.  See also Assembly: what's the difference between `stos m32` and `stosd` mnemonic? for another example.
It's a bit weird that it only uses EAX instead of EDX:EAX or edx,eax since it's making up its own syntax anyway.  What's the point of making one register operand explicit when there's still another that's implicit?  I guess you could argue that EDX:EAX is a pair addressed by its lower half.
Of course, it's easier to read disassembly and to copy/paste it into asm source files you're working on if it uses the same syntax as an assembler you're using.  I don't know if MASM accepts this or not.  If it does, it should only accept eax (or rax/ax/al) as the first operand.  (I've heard of bad assemblers that accept misleading operands as the placeholder for an implicit operand or otherwise assembling a non-encodeable instruction to machine code that does something different.)

This is different from CS:APP example uses idivq with two operands? - that's a case of totally fake assembly purportedly generated by GCC, but actually made up by some clowns hired by a publisher to mess up the practice problems in the global edition of CS:APP 3e.  In that case they're showing a form with an immediate source and RCX destination, neither of which are possible!

The disassembly is technically wrong. It just shows how idiv works. The idiv instruction always uses eax (in fact edx:eax pair) to get the dividend from and to store the result (quotient and remainder).

This seems to be correct. Unfortunately, there does not appear to be any documentation of the assembly syntax produced by the Visual Studio debugger and by dumpbin. If even a basic arithmetic instruction doesn't match the usual format, I shudder to think what other "helpful" changes Microsoft has made to more obscure instructions.

@CuriousProgrammer: I wouldn't be too worried; normal math instructions (other than x87 FP) don't have any implicit operands, and each operand can only be register or memory, or immediate.  They're trying to be helpful, I assume, not intentionally obscure, so they're not going to reorder the operands of cmp when both operands are regs or something, or write 123 as [123] even though those mean the same thing in MASM syntax because it sucks. (Confusing brackets in MASM32)

@CuriousProgrammer: Fun fact: AT&T syntax does reverse the operands to some x87 instructions when both operands are registers, due to a bug in the original UnixWare assembler which later assemblers chose to be bug-compatible with.  https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.12/as.info/i386-Bugs.html#i386-Bugs  For a while, even objdump -Mintel and other things based on GNU Binutils would do the same reversal, but IIRC it's fixed now; in Intel mode they match ndisasm and other disassemblers not polluted by that brain-rot.
